# How to Change Search View Icon in android without using Menu bar?

Tags: android

I want to use search view in linear layout not in menu action, bar but icon of my search view does not change. My XML code is:

```
     <SearchView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:icon="@mipmap/audio"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:commitIcon="@color/accent_material_light" />
```

Comment: Have you solved your problem?